# Laravel eloquent query, chaining groupBy on main query & subquery callback function

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I tried to query Item model & group by groupId, then further group the group by user_id & sum the sales_count but got an error. Below is my code.

```
$items = Item::where('sold', true)->get()->groupBy('groupId', function ($query){
          $query->select(DB::raw('userid,sum(sales_count) as total_sales_count'))->groupBy('userid');
})->get();
```

I got the error below:

```
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in
```

Expected result (Eloquent\Collection):

```
[
    17558 => [
        [
        "userid" => "2"
        "total_sales_count" => "3"
        ],
         [
        "userid" => "4"
        "total_sales_count" => "1"
        ],
    ],

    18647 => [
        [
        "userid" => "5"
        "total_sales_count" => "6"
        ],
         [
        "userid" => "7"
        "total_sales_count" => "4"
        ],
    ]
]
```

Model Structure:

```
Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('userid');
            $table->integer('sales_count')->default(1);
            $table->string('groupId')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('sold')->default(true);
        
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Comment: delete the first `get()` and try

Comment: I tried that and got this error: ```stripos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this -

```
$item = Item::where('sold', true)
        ->select('user_id', DB::raw('sum(items.sales_count) as total_sales_count'))
        ->groupBy('groupId')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I tried this an got this error:     ``` SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'mydb.items.user_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select `user_id`, sum(sales_count) as total_sales_count from `items` group by `groupId`)```

Comment: can you please share your table structure?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the model structure.